# IDE: Weird colors in html id and class parameter values

Tags: html, netbeans, syntax-highlighting

I just started using Netbeans and I love it, but I can't seem to find where to change the font of html id and class parameter values, and its currently the same color as my tags with a random background color.

I've been playing around in Tools->Options->Fonts->Syntax but I can't seem to find the correct rites and invocations to change this.

Where should I be looking?

Here is a technical read out that illustrates the problem:
[image]

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The values for class and id attributes are actually CSS selectors, which have a different syntax highlighting than normal HTML parameter values. To modify these you should alter the value of the Selector category in the Cascading Style Sheets language in the syntax tab of the fonts & colors options screen.

Comment: Tried that one :(  Here is a screenshot to better explain what I'm seeing

Comment: Hmmmm weird, especially that two colors are used in what your editor actually displays. Another idea I had, could it be that your document contains syntax errors? I have noticed some syntax coloring errors in Netbeans when you have syntax errors in your document.

Comment: no errors, in html 4.01 strict the only warning is about my icecream.  My suspician is that the ide knows id and class are special so its trying to help by pulling colors from somewhere else, but where I have no clue

Comment: Have you tried restoring the Netbeans default Profile and making the change again?

Comment: Good idea:  In the default, vanilla is orange, and the ids and classes are bold green with the same lightblue-green background

Comment: @Matt I updated my answer, I think this updated answer is the solution you are looking for.

Comment: I've also had exactly the same problem. I had tried changing the CSS colours too, but it didn't work. Turned out I needed to restart Netbeans to make it apply. Not sure why, as some other colour changes didn't need a restart.

Comment: Useful for me. Thank you mate !! :)

Answer (score 7):

What you are looking for is NOT in the `Cascading Style Sheets` section like many are saying. What your looking for is in the `HTML` section under the `Fonts and colors`. Look for `Css Embedded in HTML`. This is what you are looking for. Hope this helps.

*I'm using Netbeans 7.4

Answer (score 2):

You can change the color from **cascading style sheets** under **selector** and restart NetBeans.

Answer (score 1):

Can be changed through the Fonts & Colors options, then select the Cascading Stylesheet category and find "Mark Occurences" on the list. From there, you can change the background and foreground colors for that syntax.

Answer (score 0):

I have recently had the same problem and actually did not find the solution from the other posts, so I thought to share what I found. Your question is broken down in two sub-questions (direct reference):

1. *where to change the font of html id and class parameter values*

For that, I found that both the accepted and @user3267044 answers work. They change both class and id's parameters though, not only class parameters background color as shown in your question

2. *and its currently the same color as my tags with a random background color.*

There should be a warning on the line where the "weird" highlight appears. In my case, the warning/hint was "Missing CSS class". You can disable it from Editor --> Hints (select HTML) and then disable the hint "Missing CSS class" (or the one that applies to your case)